# Active Record Query for belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am using rails 4.2. and have the following structure:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :records
end

class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :drop
end

class Drop < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :records
end
```

I want to get all the records for a specific user (e.g. Record.where(user_id: current_user.id) but include the drop for each record. I can't get the query right. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out. To join the tables you need a "select" clause and specify which columns you want. The query was then:

```
current_user.drops.joins(:records).select("drops.*, records.*")
```